# SQL dataframe first and last not returning "real" first and last values

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-sql

I tried using the Apache Spark SQL dataframe's aggregate functions "first" and "last" on a large file with a spark master and 2 workers. When I do the "first" and "last" operations I am expecting back the last column from the file; but it looks like Spark is returning the "first" or "last" from the worker partitions.

Is there any way to get the "real" first and last values in aggregate functions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible depending on what you mean first "real" first and last values. For example, if you are dealing with timestamped data and "real" first value refers to the oldest record, just `orderBy` the data according to time and get the first value.

When you say `When I do the "first" and "last" operations I am expecting back the last column from the file`, I understand that you are in fact referring to the first/last row of data from the file. Please correct me if I mistook this.

Thanks.

Edit :

You can read the file in a single partition (by setting `numPartitions` = 1) and then `zipWithIndex` and finally `parallize` the resulting collection. This way you get a column to order on and you don't change the source file as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shagun. Problem is I don't have a timestamp field to order on. I'm just processing a big text file across nodes with only 1 column i.e. text. and I want to get the last line of the text file. Problem is first and last behavior is nondeterministic.
As a workaround, I would need to have another column (i.e. timestamp) to sort by; and I don't have the ability to modify the source text file.

Comment: I am not sure how to keep a track of order of records without having any ordering column. One thing to do is to add another column of number with each record which says that the particular record is first record, second record and so on. You can make a copy of source file, do this modification and then discard the new file. Or you can read the file in single partition (by setting numPartitions = 1) and then zipWithIndex and finally parallize the resulting collection. This way you get a column to order on and you don't change the source file as well.